# Prevent "Antlr4.Runtime.NoViableAltException" with Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm using Antlr 4 (C# implementation) and I'm getting the following exception whenever the string to parse is complex.

```
A first chance exception of type 'Antlr4.Runtime.NoViableAltException' occurred in DataImportClassLibrary.dll
```

This one works:

```
[Pitch Angle] > 5
```

This one generates the error:

```
[Pitch Angle] > 5 AND [Pressure Altitude] < 10000
```

Grammar:

```
grammar EventDetection;

AND : 'AND' ;
OR  : 'OR' ;

GT : '>' ;
GE : '>=' ;
LT : '<' ;
LE : '<=' ;
EQ : '=' ;

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;

DECIMAL : '-'?[0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)? ;
IDENTIFIER : '[' [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9 ]* ']';
SEMI : ';' ;
COMMENT : '//' .+? ('\n'|EOF);// -> skip ;
WS : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+;// -> skip ;

rule_set : single_rule* ;

single_rule : logical_expr ;

logical_expr : logical_expr AND logical_expr  # LogicalExpressionAnd
             | logical_expr OR logical_expr   # LogicalExpressionOr
             | comparison_expr                # ComparisonExpression
             | LPAREN logical_expr RPAREN     # LogicalExpressionInParen
             ;

comparison_expr : IDENTIFIER comp_operator DECIMAL  # ComparisonExpressionWithOperator
            ;

comp_operator : GT
              | GE
              | LT
              | LE
              | EQ
              ;
```

1. Is there a way to force the lexer to prioritize rules? E.g. If it just picked OR first I don't think I'd have this issue.
2. Do I need to handle this in the code?

Comment: It is not priority that leads to this exception, so you should spend more time debugging the grammar, such as debugging the generated code on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with white spaces. If I changed the input string to:

```
[Pitch Angle]>5AND[Pressure Altitude]<10000
```

it worked, even though I had a rule to handle white spaces.

The solution was to change it to the following:

```
WS : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Thanks to those who looked into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used your grammar file and was able to parse both input strings that you provided.

In order to get this to work, I uncommented the "-> skip;" you had in your rules. Can you try that out?

```
COMMENT : '//' .+? ('\n'|EOF) -> skip ;
WS : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you define `AND` as the first alternative inside `logical_expr`, the generated parser will first parse `5 AND [Pressure Altitude]`, not `[Pitch Angle] > 5`.

You'll probably want to define `comparison_expr` before `AND` and `OR`:

```
logical_expr : comparison_expr                # ComparisonExpression
             | logical_expr AND logical_expr  # LogicalExpressionAnd
             | logical_expr OR logical_expr   # LogicalExpressionOr
             | LPAREN logical_expr RPAREN     # LogicalExpressionInParen
             ;
```

Comment: Thanks Bart. Unfortunately that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Okay, could you then edit your question and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that others can reproduce the error?